# How practical is it to host Apache and mySQL/PostreSQL on the same Linux box?

Tags: php, apache, hosting, lamp

I'd like to set up a LAMP (or LAPP) web server for hosting Internet sites. Assuming no more than moderate traffic, are there practical concerns against setting it all up on the same machine (or, in this case, VPS?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No problems with it, other than performance considerations.  Space from DB and logs from Apache might eat your space faster than usual, so you might wanna think up something smart (quicker log rotation, feeding through bzip2) before you go live with it.